# Why does this function not return a value?

Tags: python, function, easygui

Be forewarned, I just started learning Python, and its my first time on this site. If I act like a n00b, please don't hate.

So I have created a program that is supposed to tell you how long it will take you to get to a star (distance is specified) at the speed of light, and factors of the speed of light. It begins with a library called easygui, which creates a nice window, which the user chooses a factor. The factor they have chosen becomes the variable "choice". This section of the code works fine. Ideally, this value would then be fed into a function, which would do the factoring, and return a value for the number of days of travel. This is unsuccessful. Most likely, I have simply set this up wrong, so if anyone knows the proper way to use functions, I'd really appreciate your help! Oh, and I tried to comment like crazy, so hopefully everything makes sense!

```
import easygui as eg                #the gui creation library I am using

dist  = 41000000000000          #distance to the star
light = 300000                  #speed of light


def Convert (factor):           #takes in factor chosen by user
    speed = light*factor        #the speed is the factor multiplied by the speed of light
    time = (dist/speed)/3600    # the time is the distance/divided by the speed, since thats a huge value in seconds, the /3600 should reduce it to days
    return time                 #"should" return the value it got for "time"


msg     = "Choose a warp factor:"                   #creates a gui  window for user to select factor
title   = "Warp Factor Selection"
choices = ["1", "3", "5", "10", "50", "100", "200", "500", "1000"]
choice   = eg.buttonbox(msg, title, choices)        #gui returns the user's selection as "choice" WORKS!

choice = float(choice)                                      #changes choice to float

if choice == 1:
    Convert(choice)                                         #attempts to feed  "choice" into the function "convert" DOES NOT WORK :(
    print (Convert(1))                                      #then print the value created from convert (have also tried print(time) but it always returns 0)
```

At this point in time, it is intentionally set up to only accept the choice of 1 as the factor. I want to figure this function thing out before I go and do the rest of the possible factors

Comment: thefourtheye beat me to it. I just want to say though, for a beginner, good job maintaining really clean code and adding all the comments to make it easy for people to answer your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
(dist/speed)/3600
```

if the `(dist/speed)` is lesser than 3600, result will be 0. You can try that out yourself,

```
print 3599/3600
```

will print

```
0
```

So, you need to convert the data to float like this

```
def Convert (factor):
    speed = light*factor
    return (float(dist)/float(speed))/3600.0
```

Comment: Using python 3 this shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 5):

thefourtheye already explained why, but if you want to avoid this in the future you could switch to Python 3 division by putting this at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import division
```

In Python 3, it behaves more intuitively in situations like this (`1/2 == .5`) while you can still get the integer division behavior with `//` (`1//2 == 0`)

Comment: Nice alternative, I did not know this about Python 3!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do this

```
if str(choice) in choices:
    Convert(choice)
    print (Convert(choice))
```

That way, you don't have to make a new if condition to test each number. This just says that if `choice` is in `choices` list, execute the function with `choice`.

Comment: Thanks, anything that helps me reduce the code will make it look cleaner/neater when it gets marked. I appreciate your input/advice!